# json Store not updating values correctly kivy

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, kivy

I am inserting a value in a Json file using json store first from a function from current code and then from a function from a different code using , but when i update the value second time it resets the value which i set in first code .

I am sure you will understand it better from the sample code below :

I have 2 files :

1. jsonstore.py    - which will further import importedmodule which is file 2
2. importedmodule.py

PLease see below code on both files .

jsonstore.py

```
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
import importedmodule as jb

JsonFileName = 'a.json'
store = JsonStore(JsonFileName)

def hello():
    store.put('ten', v=int(10))

hello()
jb.hello()
```

importedmodule.py

```
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore

JsonFileName = 'a.json'
store = JsonStore(JsonFileName)

def hello():
    store.put('twenty', v=int(20))
```

I want that when i run 1st file code i.t. jsonstore.py its output should be as :

```
{"twenty": {"v": 20}, "ten": {"v": 10}}
```

but i am getting output as

```
{"twenty": {"v": 20}, "ten": {"v": 0}}
```

I am not sure why is it not updating value of ten as 10 . Not sure what is wrong or what i am doing wrong . Can anyone help me or advice .?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating two `JsonStore`s. This is like opening the same text file in two separate editors, then making changes and saving each copy of the file - only one copy will be saved, and the other will be overwritten. Try using the same store for each method.

**jsonstore.py**

```
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
import importedmodule as jb

JsonFileName = 'a.json'
store = JsonStore(JsonFileName)

def hello(s):
    s.put('ten', v=int(10))

hello(store)
jb.hello(store)
```

**importedmodule.py**

```
def hello(s):
    s.put('twenty', v=int(20))
```

Comment: this works ... also if i open the store file in the function in file 2 also works . Thanks !!